# What does is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL' mean?

Tags: r, na, cox-regression

I want to select a Cox model with the forward procedure from a data.frame with no NA. Here is some sample data:

```
test <- data.frame(
  x_1   = runif(100,0,1),
  x_2   = runif(100,0,5),
  x_3   = runif(100,10,20),
  time  = runif(100,50,200),
  event = c(rep(0,70),rep(1,30))
)
```

This table has no signification but if we try to build a model anyway :

```
modeltest <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~1, test)
modeltest.forward <- step(
  modeltest, 
  data      = test, 
  direction = "forward", 
  scope     = list(lower = ~ 1, upper = ~ x_1 + x_2 + x_3)
)
```

The forward ends at the first step and says:

> In is.na(fit$coefficients) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

(three times)

I tried to change the upper model, I even tried `upper = ~ 1` but the warning stays. I don't understand: I have no NAs and my vectors are all numerics (I checked it).
I searched if people had the same issue but all I could find was problems due to the name or class of the vectors.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I forgot to say that if i try something like modeltest<-coxph(Surv(time, event) ~x_1,data=test), this works. The problem seems to be in the forward but i don't understand why neither how to solve it.

Comment: If I change coxph(Surv) to lm(event) or lm(time), it works. I would therefore come from the combination of forward and coxph ?

Comment: Hi @Vincent! Were you able to solve the problem? The same error is appearing with a cox model and I don't seem to understand why is it..

Comment: Well yes and no : with my current version of R (3.0.3), I don't get errors running the above code but only warnings, and the step function works. The explanation is that a null cox model has no coefficients, not even an intercept, unlike a null linear model. So when the `step` function verifies if the models are ok (no NA in the estimations), it can't find any estimation for the null model which causes the error/warnings. Thus, the warning is ignorable without jeopardizing the outcome quality. If you get an error, maybe try to install a more recent version of R ?

Comment: Thank you! I will try to install a newer version. I was trying to use anova to compare the null model with others models but the error was appearing. One problem should be not having an intercept but that sounds a bit weird to me.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with `dredge` function applied to a `coxph`model with several covariates. Do you conclude that this could be a bug? (A few days ago it worked just fine)

Comment: I wouldn't say a bug, it's just that `step` (and i'm assuming `dredge ` too) can't deal with a model that have no coefficient. Does the error remain if you set m.min=1 ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### The problem in this specific case

The right hand side of your formula is `1`, which makes it a *null model*.  `coxph` calls `coxph.fit`, which (perhaps lazily) doesn't bother to return coefficients for null models.

Later `coxph` calls `extractAIC`, which erroneously assumes that the model object contains an element named `coefficients`.

### The general case

`is.na` assumes that its input argument is an atomic vector or a matrix or a list or a data.frame.  Other data types cause the warning.  It happens with `NULL`, as you've seen:

```
is.na(NULL)
## logical(0)
## Warning message:
## In is.na(NULL) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

One common cause of this problem is trying to access elements of a list, or columns of a data frame that don't exist.

```
d <- data.frame(x = c(1, NA, 3))
d$y # "y" doesn't exist is the data frame, but NULL is returned
## NULL
is.na(d$y)
## logical(0)
## Warning message:
## In is.na(d$y) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

You can protect against this by checking that the column exists before you manipulate it.

```
if("y" in colnames(d))
{
  d2 <- d[is.na(d$y), ]
}
```

### The warning with other data types

You get a simliar warning with formulae, functions, expressions, etc.:

```
is.na(~ NA)
## [1] FALSE FALSE
## Warning message:
## In is.na(~NA) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'

is.na(mean)
## [1] FALSE
## Warning message:
## In is.na(mean) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'

is.na(is.na)
## [1] FALSE
## Warning message:
## In is.na(is.na) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'builtin'

is.na(expression(NA))
## [1] FALSE
## Warning message:
## In is.na(expression(NA)) :
##   is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression'
```

Comment: The 'other data types' bit is really useful. Could you add an example which triggers `... of type 'symbol'` too?

Comment: @LondonRob Well `is.na(as.symbol("x"))` would do it, but I'm guessing that this has been caused by some non-standard evaluation somewhere. Consider creating a new question describing your problem, and linking to this question, stating that you have a special case of this more general issue.