# Rstudio is.na(e2) error when sourcing r file of functions

Tags: r

This doesn't seem to be affecting my code, but it's driving me crazy. I have a file with a bunch of custom functions I'm using for analysis. Whenever I source the file, I get the following message, sometime up to 26 times:

```
Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e2) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'
2: In is.na(e2) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'
```

I understand intuitively and from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209643/what-does-is-na-applied-to-non-list-or-vector-of-type-null-mean) what the error message means, but I don't understand why it is happening when I source the file with the functions or how to make it stop.

Comment: if it doesnt affect your result dont worry about it, its not an error message simply a warning message. also, without your original code how are we suppose to help you out?

Comment: Totally get it that you would have to have the code to understand what's causing the precise error, I just didn't know if this was something others had encountered. I don't want you to have to wade through the swamp of my custom (and likely horrendous to the outside observer) functions :)

Comment: Is there a way to track down and debug warnings?

Comment: the warning isnt a bug -it's warning you that you cannot apply ``is.na()`` to something other than a vector or list...

Comment: if you use `option(warn = 2)` warnings are promoted to errors and you can use standard tools (traceback) to find the where the problem is occurring.